# Is API hooking done by a process in a shared page, visible to all other processes?

Tags: windows, malware, exploit, injection

Assume, I have an executable which hooks the API `CreateFileW` located in `Kernel32.dll` which is shared globally across the system for all other processes. From hooking I mean, that I have overwritten the prologue of `CreateFileW`

```
jmp Hook_CreateFileW
nop
// ...rest of original CreateFileW code...
```

My Doubt::

From what I know, `Kernel32.dll` will be loaded at some address which is global across the system and its pages are shared across the processes. So, does hooking `CreateFileW` in my exe, means that it is hooked for all other processes too ? Any other process, which would call `CreateFileW` will try to jump `Hook_CreateFileW` ?

Comment: Executables are mapped as copy-on-write, not as shared memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, all API hooking (IAT, EAT, Detouring and so on) only affects process you are modifying as the PE loader grabs a local copy of Kernel32 instead of using shared code.

You would need to inject all processes with your hook to effect all processes you'll require SeDebugPrivilege to open certain system processes.

If you want to go any deep you could hook SSDT in kernel or could modify .text directly but comes a problem with x64 PatchGuard.

What makes you want to hook CreateFileW anyways? Maybe there is a better solution for your requirements?

The reason why you see same address across processes you can set a preferred base address for your modules. If the address is not in-use you'll get that memory space, if not it will be relocated. Since Kernel32 (depending on PE) is loaded very early stages unlikely the other non-system modules. So, Kernel32 will generally always get it's preferred base address. You can however relocate it so don't rely on the address been static.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but I still have the doubt on how does a shared page hides itself from all other processes or do all processes acquire a local page of Kernel32 (I dont' think so) ?

Comment: You can set a preferred base address for your modules. If the address is not in-use you'll get that memory space, if not it will be relocated. Since Kernel32 (depending on PE) is loaded very early stages unlikely the other non-system modules. So, Kernel32 will generally always get it's preferred base address. You can however relocate it so don't rely on the address been static.

Comment: To expand on my previous comment and answer it directly; All processes get a local copy of Kernel32 into the virtual memory space of the process hence why hooking doesn't globally affect all processes.

Comment: Thanks. You last comment clarifies alot. Would you please update the same in your answer ? I will wait for sometime before accepting for others to provide solutions.